# Why type of @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid") is varchar(36) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, mysql-8.0, nestjs-typeorm

`@PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")`

This decorator is create VARCHAR(36).

UUID length is 36. But what reason don't use CHAR(36)?

- typeorm: 0.3.17
- mysql2: 3.6.0
- @nestjs/typeorm: 10.0.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgvNY.png)

My mysql database version is 8.1.0

Comment: This would be better asked in TypeORM's repository, as it is an implementation question

Comment: See https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7228